# XSLT - field content validation inside loop

Tags: xslt

I'm facing an issue in production which I'd like your help to understand what would be the best option of XSLT code change to fix it.
I have the following source structure that needs to be transformed inside my middleware:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:SMRESULTS xmlns:ns0="http://www.mycompany.com/SYS/SCENARIO/VERSION">
   <ns0:PREAMBLE>
      <ns0:I_SITE_CODE/>
      <ns0:I_DESTINATION/>
      <ns0:I_FILENAME/>
      <ns0:I_RECORD_TYPE/>
   </ns0:PREAMBLE>
   <ns0:SAMPLES>
      <ns0:SAMPLE>
         <ns0:S_APPROVAL_REASON/>
         <ns0:D_TANK_CONFORMITY/>
         <ns0:D_SAMPLE>
            <ns0:D_SAMPLE_ID/>
            <ns0:D_SAMPLE_VALUE/>
         </ns0:D_SAMPLE>
         <ns0:TESTS>
            <ns0:TEST>
               <ns0:T_ANALYSIS/>
               <ns0:T_AUTHORISATION_COMMENT/>
               <ns0:D_TEST>
                  <ns0:D_TEST_ID/>
                  <ns0:D_TEST_VALUE/>
               </ns0:D_TEST>
               <ns0:RESULTS>
                  <ns0:RESULT>
                     <ns0:R_VALUE/>
                     <ns0:D_GRDB_PROPERTY/>
                     <ns0:D_RESULT>
                        <ns0:D_RESULT_ID/>
                        <ns0:D_RESULT_VALUE/>
                     </ns0:D_RESULT>
                  </ns0:RESULT>
               </ns0:RESULTS>
            </ns0:TEST>
         </ns0:TESTS>
      </ns0:SAMPLE>
   </ns0:SAMPLES>
</ns0:SMRESULTS>
```

My requirement is that whenever a "<" sign is found (characteristic D_RESULT_ID = 'Sm.Result.Min_Limit' and D_RESULT_VALUE = `<![CDATA[<=600.0000]]>`
the value must be transferred to 'Sm.Result.Max_Limit' characteristic and the characteristic 'Sm.Result.Min_Limit' must be blanked out.

Exemplifying: For the below source data...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
   <SMRESULTS  xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/SYS/SCENARIO/VERSION" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <PREAMBLE>
         <I_SITE_CODE>Site Code</I_SITE_CODE>
         <I_DESTINATION>Destination</I_DESTINATION>
         <I_FILENAME>filename.zzz</I_FILENAME>
         <I_RECORD_TYPE>INSERT</I_RECORD_TYPE>
      </PREAMBLE>
      <SAMPLES>
         <SAMPLE>
            <S_APPROVAL_REASON></S_APPROVAL_REASON>
            <D_TANK_CONFORMITY></D_TANK_CONFORMITY>
            <D_SAMPLE>
               <D_SAMPLE_ID>Sm.Sample.BatchId</D_SAMPLE_ID>
               <D_SAMPLE_VALUE></D_SAMPLE_VALUE>
            </D_SAMPLE>
            <D_SAMPLE>
               <D_SAMPLE_ID>Sm.Sample.Type</D_SAMPLE_ID>
               <D_SAMPLE_VALUE></D_SAMPLE_VALUE>
            </D_SAMPLE>
            <D_SAMPLE>
               <D_SAMPLE_ID>SM.Sample.Template_ID</D_SAMPLE_ID>
               <D_SAMPLE_VALUE>SPEP-PE</D_SAMPLE_VALUE>
            </D_SAMPLE>
            <TESTS>
               <TEST>
                  <T_ANALYSIS>AnalysisCode</T_ANALYSIS>
                  <D_TEST>
                     <D_TEST_ID>Sm.Test.DerivedGRDBTestMethod</D_TEST_ID>
                     <D_TEST_VALUE></D_TEST_VALUE>
                  </D_TEST>
                  <RESULTS>
                     <RESULT  xsi:nil="false">
                        <R_VALUE>0.000</R_VALUE>
                        <D_GRDB_PROPERTY></D_GRDB_PROPERTY>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.DerivedGRDBUOM</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE></D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.Min_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE></D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.Max_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE></D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.FailedCriticalLvl</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE>false</D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                     </RESULT>
                     <RESULT  xsi:nil="false">
                        <R_VALUE>0.000</R_VALUE>
                        <D_GRDB_PROPERTY></D_GRDB_PROPERTY>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.DerivedGRDBUOM</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE></D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.Min_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE></D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.Max_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE></D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.FailedCriticalLvl</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE>false</D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                     </RESULT>
                     <RESULT  xsi:nil="false">
                        <R_VALUE>344.712</R_VALUE>
                        <D_GRDB_PROPERTY>ASH</D_GRDB_PROPERTY>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.DerivedGRDBUOM</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE>59W</D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.Min_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE><![CDATA[<=600.0000]]></D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.Max_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE></D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                        <D_RESULT>
                           <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.FailedCriticalLvl</D_RESULT_ID>
                           <D_RESULT_VALUE>false</D_RESULT_VALUE>
                        </D_RESULT>
                     </RESULT>
                  </RESULTS>
               </TEST>
            </TESTS>
         </SAMPLE>
      </SAMPLES>
   </SMRESULTS>
```

...the desired result should be as follow:

```
...
            <RESULT>
              <R_VALUE>344.712</R_VALUE>
              <D_GRDB_PROPERTY>ASH</D_GRDB_PROPERTY>
              <D_RESULT>
                <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.DerivedGRDBUOM</D_RESULT_ID>
                <D_RESULT_VALUE>59W</D_RESULT_VALUE>
              </D_RESULT>
              <D_RESULT>
                <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.Min_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                <D_RESULT_VALUE/>
              </D_RESULT>
              <D_RESULT>
                <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.Max_Limit</D_RESULT_ID>
                <D_RESULT_VALUE><![CDATA[<=600.0000]]></D_RESULT_VALUE>
              </D_RESULT>
              <D_RESULT>
                <D_RESULT_ID>Sm.Result.FailedCriticalLvl</D_RESULT_ID>
                <D_RESULT_VALUE>false</D_RESULT_VALUE>
              </D_RESULT>
            </RESULT>
...
```

I have to do this adjust in the current XSLT, which is as follow:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://www.mycompany.com/SYS/SCENARIO/VERSION" xmlns:map="java:java.util.Map" xmlns:dyn="java:com.sap.aii.mapping.api.DynamicConfiguration" xmlns:key="java:com.sap.aii.mapping.api.DynamicConfigurationKey" xmlns:javamap="java:package.xi.common.util.DateConversion">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="inputparam"/>
    <xsl:param name="Region">
        <xsl:text>UTC</xsl:text>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="DateTimeFormat">
        <xsl:text>yyyyMMdd_HHmmss</xsl:text>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="DYNAMIC_CONFIG_NS_FILE">
        <xsl:text>http://sap.com/xi/XI/System/File</xsl:text>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="DYNAMIC_CONFIG_KEY">
        <xsl:text>FileName</xsl:text>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="SampleID">
        <xsl:value-of select="a:SMRESULTS/a:SAMPLES/a:SAMPLE/a:S_ID_NUMERIC"/>
    </xsl:param>
    <!-- Call the getCurrentDateTime function from Global Services.-->
    <xsl:param name="CurrentDateTime">
        <xsl:if test="function-available('javamap:getCurrentDateTime')">
            <xsl:value-of select="javamap:getCurrentDateTime($Region, $DateTimeFormat)"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="DynFileName">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat($SampleID,'_',$CurrentDateTime,'.xml')"/>
    </xsl:param>
    <!-- Set File Name in Dynamic Configuration.-->
    <xsl:variable name="DynamicConf" select="map:get($inputparam, 'DynamicConfiguration')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="DynamicKey" select="key:create($DYNAMIC_CONFIG_NS_FILE, $DYNAMIC_CONFIG_KEY)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="FileName" select="dyn:put($DynamicConf, $DynamicKey, $DynFileName)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <SMRESULTS xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/SYS/SCENARIO/VERSION">
            <PREAMBLE>
                <I_SITE_CODE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="a:SMRESULTS/a:PREAMBLE/a:I_SITE_CODE"/>
                </I_SITE_CODE>
                <I_DESTINATION>
                    <xsl:value-of select="a:SMRESULTS/a:PREAMBLE/a:I_DESTINATION"/>
                </I_DESTINATION>
                <I_FILENAME>
                    <xsl:value-of select="a:SMRESULTS/a:PREAMBLE/a:I_FILENAME"/>
                </I_FILENAME>
                <I_RECORD_TYPE>
                    <xsl:value-of select="a:SMRESULTS/a:PREAMBLE/a:I_RECORD_TYPE"/>
                </I_RECORD_TYPE>
            </PREAMBLE>
            <SAMPLES>
                <SAMPLE>
                    <S_APPROVAL_REASON>
                        <xsl:value-of select="a:SMRESULTS/a:SAMPLES/a:SAMPLE/a:S_APPROVAL_REASON"/>
                    </S_APPROVAL_REASON>
                    <D_TANK_CONFORMITY>
                        <xsl:value-of select="a:SMRESULTS/a:SAMPLES/a:SAMPLE/a:D_TANK_CONFORMITY"/>
                    </D_TANK_CONFORMITY>
                    <xsl:for-each select="/a:SMRESULTS/a:SAMPLES/a:SAMPLE/a:D_SAMPLE">
                        <D_SAMPLE>
                            <D_SAMPLE_ID>
                                <xsl:value-of select="a:D_SAMPLE_ID"/>
                            </D_SAMPLE_ID>
                            <D_SAMPLE_VALUE>
                                <xsl:value-of select="a:D_SAMPLE_VALUE"/>
                            </D_SAMPLE_VALUE>
                        </D_SAMPLE>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <TESTS>
                        <xsl:for-each select="a:SMRESULTS/a:SAMPLES/a:SAMPLE/a:TESTS/a:TEST">
                            <TEST>
                                <T_ANALYSIS>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="a:T_ANALYSIS"/>
                                </T_ANALYSIS>
                                <T_AUTHORISATION_COMMENT>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="a:T_AUTHORISATION_COMMENT"/>
                                </T_AUTHORISATION_COMMENT>
                                <xsl:for-each select="a:D_TEST">
                                    <D_TEST>
                                        <D_TEST_ID>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="a:D_TEST_ID"/>
                                        </D_TEST_ID>
                                        <D_TEST_VALUE>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="a:D_TEST_VALUE"/>
                                        </D_TEST_VALUE>
                                    </D_TEST>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                                <RESULTS>
                                    <xsl:for-each select="a:RESULTS/a:RESULT">
                                        <RESULT>
                                            <R_VALUE>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="a:R_VALUE" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                                            </R_VALUE>
                                            <D_GRDB_PROPERTY>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="a:D_GRDB_PROPERTY" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                                            </D_GRDB_PROPERTY>
                                            <xsl:for-each select="a:D_RESULT">
                                                <D_RESULT>
                                                    <D_RESULT_ID>
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="a:D_RESULT_ID"/>
                                                    </D_RESULT_ID>
                                                    <D_RESULT_VALUE>
                                                        <xsl:value-of select="a:D_RESULT_VALUE"/>
                                                    </D_RESULT_VALUE>
                                                </D_RESULT>
                                            </xsl:for-each>
                                        </RESULT>
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </RESULTS>
                            </TEST>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </TESTS>
                </SAMPLE>
            </SAMPLES>
        </SMRESULTS>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have removed some unnecessary directly-mapped fields just to make it shorter.

Any comments/suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is it intentional in your example output that you have a pair of double quotes after the transferred value that were not present in the input value?

Comment: Is it desirable to convert the element content from a CDATA section to ordinary PCDATA, as you have done? Is it acceptable for it to remain a CDATA section (so long as it is moved)?

Comment: John, I've mistyped the double quotes. I've corrected. You got it right, I have to move the field content from Min_Limit to Max_Limit whenever I see a "<" character as part of its content. Thank you!

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to modify the content of the <RESULT> node independently of the data that contains it. It also looks like all the rest of the content is just copied from the source. I would simplify the xslt by using an "XSLT identity transform" to copy the document content unmodified. Then create a template that matches the RESULT node. In that template use <xsl:if> (or xsl:choose) to produce the correct RESULT output. Since xsl proceeds from least specific to most specific your second template will produce the correct result node in spite of the overlap with the identity.

Comment: Jay, most of the target structure is copy of source. The fix has to be very well documented, detailed and explained due to fact of being an enhancement in production code (very bureaucratic process) . So, unfortunately, changing the whole thing is not an option for me. I tried to fix this question by using some variables but it does not help at all since RESULT structure with Min/Max limits might arrive more than once. Really appreciate if you could help further with all these limitations in mind. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RafaVieira, the starting stylesheet you presented, as applied to the example input you presented, appears to do *nothing* but copy the input to the output (in an unbelievably verbose way).  I don't see how that could be serving any useful purpose in production.

Comment: You're partially right. Basically, it does nothing in the structure but it sets some parameters dynamically to the target adapter through DYNAMIC_CONFIG_NS_FILE and DYNAMIC_CONFIG_KEY. I'm not allowed to replace it by another solution. I have to enhance it as it is. I got a good answer in this question - 30261569, but I just don't understand how to adapt my code with the one Michael has suggested, 'cause, again, I cannot replace the current solution.

Comment: @RafaVieira, I wish you had told us about your other question at the beginning.  It would have saved me a considerable amount of time.

Comment: John, I preferred to not mention about that other topic since its original text was changed and the comments are all confusing. But as you said it could have saved you much time, I apologize. Really appreciate your help! The only thing I don't see this code doing is the CDATA being moved to Max_Limit. It is gotten from Min_Limit as <![CDATA[<=600.0000]]> and goes to Max_Limit as &lt;=600.0000. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing transform is horrible.  You have my sympathy.

Nevertheless, you should be able to achieve the behavior you describe by modifying the template fragment for the content of `<D_RESULT_VALUE>` elements, along the same lines as the solution you were offered in your other question.  Here's the relevant fragment of the updated stylesheet (a little wider than the actual change, so as to make the context of the XPath expressions clear; also, dedented):

```
<xsl:for-each select="a:D_RESULT">
    <D_RESULT>
        <D_RESULT_ID>
            <xsl:value-of select="a:D_RESULT_ID"/>
        </D_RESULT_ID>
        <D_RESULT_VALUE>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="a:D_RESULT_ID='Sm.Result.Max_Limit' and ../a:D_RESULT[a:D_RESULT_ID='Sm.Result.Min_Limit'][contains(a:D_RESULT_VALUE, '&lt;')]">
                  <xsl:value-of select="../a:D_RESULT[a:D_RESULT_ID='Sm.Result.Min_Limit']/a:D_RESULT_VALUE"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="a:D_RESULT_ID='Sm.Result.Min_Limit' and contains(., '&lt;')"/>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="a:D_RESULT_VALUE"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </D_RESULT_VALUE>
    </D_RESULT>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I don't see any way to do what you want with a smaller change.

Note that this template fragment assumes that any `<RESULT>` element that needs to be modified contains, in addition to a `<D_RESULT>` with `D_RESULT_ID='Sm.Result.Min_Limit'`, another `<D_RESULT>` with `D_RESULT_ID='Sm.Result.Max_Limit'` into which to copy the former's `<D_RESULT_VALUE>`.  If that is not the case then the transform will simply discard the `Min_Limit` value.

Moreover, when a `Min_Limit` value is copied to a `Max_Limit`, any previous value of the `Max_Limit` is irretrievably lost (but as far as I can tell, that's what you want).